# Isabelle proof error when calling sequential record operations

Tags: isabelle

I'm very new to Isabelle and proof obligations, and I'm currently translating a VDM model I made of the 'Dots and Boxes' game (the basic VDM type translations were provided for us).

So far I have two record types, a `Dot`:

```
record Dot =
    pos_x :: VDMNat1
    pos_y :: VDMNat1
```

..and a `Move` (made up of two `Dot`'s):

```
record Move =
    dot_a :: Dot
    dot_b :: Dot
```

..but now I'm attempting to translate a sequence of those `Move`'s and am experiencing a strange error with the invariant:

```
type_synonym Moves = "Move VDMSet"

definition inv_Moves :: "Moves ⇒ "
    where "inv_Moves ms ≡
        int (card ms) ≤ MAX_MOVES ∧
        (∀ m . m ∈ ms ⟶
            inv_Move m ∧
            pos_x dot_a m > 0 ∧
            pos_y dot_a m > 0 ∧
            pos_x dot_b m > 0 ∧
            pos_y dot_b m > 0 ∧
            pos_x dot_a m ≤ BOARD_WIDTH ∧
            pos_y dot_a m ≤ BOARD_HEIGHT ∧
            pos_x dot_b m ≤ BOARD_WIDTH ∧
            pos_y dot_b m ≤ BOARD_HEIGHT ∧
            inverse_move m ∉ ms)"
```

[image: Error I'm experiencing]

I know the invariant is probably worse than just this error, but as far as I can tell from the error it's having an issue with the multiple calls to the record fields; i.e. passing `dot_a` to `pos_x` instead of the result of `dot_a m`. The only solution I can think of is to manipulate the order of operations but I'm not sure how to achieve this as `pos_x dot_a m` = `pos_x (dot_a m)`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associativity of function application is the other way around: `pos_x dot_a m = (pos_x dot_a) m`. Try `pos_x (dot_a m)`.